# Axiomatic set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question is about Axiomatic set theory. Concerning formulas with free variables, we adopt the notational convention that all free variables of a formula
$\phi(u_1, . . . , u_n)$:

What's this $\phi(u_1, . . . , u_n)$ and $ u_1, . . . , u_n$?
I do not understand.

And that Axiomatic set theory : Do the same Classes
 is set??   explain more!!
thank you very much

Comment: $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ are *variables*.

Comment: The expression $\phi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ means a formula of the language of the theory with $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ as *free* (i.e. not quantified) variables. Example : $\forall x (x \in y)$ is a formula $\phi(y)$ because the variable $x$ is quantified and the variable $y$ is free.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do the same Classes is set??

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If ϕ(x, p1, . . . , pn) is a formula, we call
C = {x : ϕ(x, p1, . . . , pn)}
a class. class =set ?!!

Comment: NO; not every *class* is a set. The axiom of the theory (see your text) specify the "conditions" when the class $C = \{ x : \phi(x, p_1, \ldots, p_n) \}$ is a *set*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we write $\phi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ what we mean is that $\phi$ is a well-formed formula in your given language and that *at most* the variables $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ appear as free variables in $\phi$. Intuitively this mean that we can plug values in $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ and then evaluate the resulting statement. More precisely, we can take any sequence $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ of elements of our universe and then replace every free occurrence of $u_i$ in $\phi$ with $x_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. We write, depending on the author,

- $\phi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$,
- $\phi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)[x_1/u_1, \ldots, x_n/u_n]$,
- $\phi[x_1/u_1, \ldots, x_n/u_n]$,
- $\phi[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, or
- ...

  for the resulting statement. Consult your textbook for the precise notation it uses.

Let us consider some examples:

1. Let $\phi \equiv u_1 = u_2$. Then we would write $\phi(u_1,u_2)$, since both $u_1$ and $u_2$ occur freely in $\phi$ and those are the only free variables. If $x_1, x_2$ are elements of our universe, then
   $$\phi(u_1,u_2)[x_1,x_2] \equiv x_1 = x_2. $$
   This statement is true if $x_1 = x_2$ and false otherwise.
2. Let $\phi  \equiv \exists u_1 \colon u_1 = u_2$. This formula has two variables, $u_1$ and $u_2$, but only $u_2$ occurs freely. So we would write $\phi(u_2)$. Now for any $x_2$ in our universe we obtain the statement
   $$
   \phi(u_2)[x_2] \equiv \exists u_1 \colon u_1 = x_2
   $$
   and this statement is always true (let $u_1 := x_2$).
3. A variable can occur both freely and bounded. Let $\phi \equiv u_1 = u_2 \vee \exists u_1 \colon u_1 = u_2$. $u_1$ occurs both freely and bounded and $u_2$ occurs freely. No matter whether it occurs also bounded, since $u_1$ occurs freely we write $\phi(u_1, u_2)$. In this case, however, there is some annoying detail we have to look at. Given $x_1, x_2$ in our background universe, we want to evaluate $\phi(u_1,u_2)[x_1,x_2]$. To do so, we only replace the free occurrences of $u_1$ with $x_1$, so the resulting statement is
   $$
   \phi(u_1, u_2)[x_1, x_2] \equiv x_1 = x_2 \vee \exists u_1 \colon u_1 = x_2.
   $$
   We would now like to replace the remaining $u_1$ with $x_2$ to see that this statement is always true. However, this seems ambiguous. Should we replace the instances of $u_1$ that we already plugged $x_1$ into? So should the result be $x_2 = x_2 \vee \exists x_2 = x_2$ or should it be $x_1 = x_2 \vee \exists x_2 = x_2$? The latter is correct. More precisely, when a given variable $u_i$ occurs both freely and bounded, replace all the bounded instances of it with a variable that hasn't been used thus far. So instead of
   $$
   \phi(u_1,u_2) \equiv u_1 = u_2 \vee \exists u_1 \colon u_1 = u_2
   $$
   we let
   $$
   \phi(u_1,u_2) \equiv u_1 = u_2 \vee \exists u_3 \colon u_3 = u_2.
   $$

Regarding your second question: With every formula $\phi(u_1, \ldots, u_2)$ we can associate a *(virtual) class*

$$
C_{\phi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)} := \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mid \phi(u_1, \ldots, u_n)[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \text{ is true} \}
$$
(we usually omit the "is true").
For example, let $\phi(u_1) \equiv u_1 = u_1$. Then
$$
C_{\phi(u_1)} = \{ x_1 \mid x_1 = x_1 \}
$$
is the virtual class of all sets. This (in most commonly used set theories) is not a set. On the other hand, if $x$ is a set, then we can consider $\phi(u_1) \equiv u_1 \in \dot c$, where $\dot c$ is a constant symbol we added to our language. If we now let $\dot c = x$ in our interpretation, then
$$
\begin{align*}
C_{\phi(u_1)} &= \{ x_1 \mid \phi(u_1)[x_1] \} \\
&= \{ x_1 \mid x_1 \in \dot c \} \\
&= \{ x_1 \mid x_1 \in x \} \\
& = x,
\end{align*}
$$
so every set can be represented as a virtual class in a canonical way. (Here I assume that extensionality is an axiom of our set theory, but this is the case for any set theory that you should encounter.)